# Can row and column manipulation get the same row echelon from?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For example,say I have a matrix $A$, Use row transformation get

$$ A_r=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2 &  -1 & 5 & 2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 & 6 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} $$

Can I get the same $A_r$ use column transformation?(Not matter what $A$ is , as long as it has the same $A_r$) I knew in some cases this is true but I'm not sure whether this is true or not in general, can someone posts some Wikipedia links or some ideas related?

Further more, what if the case $A$ is $n\times n$ matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For example, consider:
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Notice that $M$ is already in reduced row echelon form so that $M_r = M$. However, if we add $(-3)$ times column one to column two, then we obtain:
$$
M_c = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is not row-equivalent to $M_r$.